# Changing map type upon zoom changes with users mouse

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a simple ROADMAP map with markers starting in a zoom level of 17 (university campus). I want to change the map type to SATELLITE when the zoom has been changed by the user to less than 14.
Doesn't seem to work. - FIXED THAT TYPO  ERROR - STILL WON'T WORK.

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.792659, 35.244251);
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
}

//zoom changes and we get a satellite map

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel <= 14) {
        map.setMapTypeId('SATELLITE');
    }
});
```

Comment: Within if condition, you have used a wrong variable `if (zmap.getZoom() <= 14) {`.

Comment: Why the close vote? The question shows effort and an attempt to solve the problem!

Comment: @Liath This is just a typo error right?  Used a wrong variable within the if conditional statement.  Therefore closed with the below reason `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.`

Comment: @Praveen - ok, I'd go with that

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you're getting map and zmap mixed up. My guess is that you've combined this from two different examples.

Try

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel <= 14) {
        map.setMapTypeId('SATELLITE');
    }
});
```